# Why does the Facebook Sharer work differently for two almost identical sites?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

So I have 2 almost identical websites
mim.aquaphor.ru & mim.aquaphor.bg (just different languages)

Facebook's sharer.php works for the first [sharer.php?u=http://mim.aquaphor.ru/](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mim.aquaphor.ru/)

But it doesn't work for the second
[sharer.php?u=http://mim.aquaphor.bg/](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mim.aquaphor.bg/) (returns blank)

Facebook debugger doesn't do much help, the same way it likes mim.aquaphor.ru & hates mim.aquaphor.bg

And the funniest thing is that they both worked about 2 weeks ago - that's for sure.

Comment: i believe there is a bug on facebook right now. also, you should not add script tags before meta tags. actually, you should not even have ANY script tag in the head section - at least not without async/defer.

Comment: This seems to be working now.